# Blynk app, DotStar bluetooth control code help

Tags: led, adafruit, blynk

This is my setup:

- Arduino Mega;
- HM-10 bluetooth module (bought off ebay, so not sure if genuine but works);
- Adafruit Dotstar addressable LED strip;
- iOS Blynk app;

Hardware-wise, everything is connected and working properly.

My ultimate goal is to implement this LED strip on my car in the headlights.

At this point though, I want to have everything working off the Blynk app with 3 on/off switch buttons, linked to 3 virtual pins and not consider any code priority for the lights.

I have 3 light "shows" for the strip, which are in their own void functions.

These are:

- Daytime runing lights: DRL();
- Signal turn indicator: STI();
- Police display: POL();

This is my first serious project so consider me a first time coder.
Each switch button should be linked to each light show and turn the strip on and off.

What I want more specifically: when I press the DRL switch, DRL should stay on. Only turn off when switch is pressed again. This works fine.

The STI I want to loop. but when I push the switch, it goes through the function only once. This is what I don't understand, as the `Blynk.run()` is in the void loop function, and the state of the virtual pin hasn't changed.

It's the same for the police lights, it goes through the sequence only once, but i want it looped.

So my question is: How can I loop the STI and POL functions in my code?

I have tried with a while function but i can't get out of it by reading the the virtual pin within the function.

Here is the entire code:

I am aware that the code might be messy, any input is appreciated.

```cpp
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#include <SPI.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleSerialBLE.h>

#include <Adafruit_DotStar.h>
#define NUMPIXELS 72

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

Adafruit_DotStar strip = Adafruit_DotStar(NUMPIXELS, DOTSTAR_BRG);

// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "***";

uint32_t amber = 0x020600;
uint32_t white = 0x020202;
uint32_t red = 0x000200;
uint32_t blue = 0x000002;
//SoftwareSerial SerialBLE(10, 11); // RX, TX


BLYNK_WRITE(V1)
{
  int pinValue1 = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1     to a variable

  if (pinValue1 == 1) {
    Serial.print("Daytime running lights: ON ");
    Serial.println(pinValue1); //showing the actual virtual pin status 0/1
    DRL();
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Daytime running lights: OFF ");
    Serial.println(pinValue1); //showing the actual virtual pin status 0/1
    OFF();
    Serial.print("off ok"); // this just helps me check where the code has   progressed
  }
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V2)
{
  int pinValue2 = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V2 to    a variable

  if (pinValue2 == 1) {
    Serial.print("Dynamic turn indicator: ON ");
    Serial.println(pinValue2);  //showing the actual virtual pin status 0/1
    STI();
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Dynamic turn indicator: OFF ");
    Serial.println(pinValue2);  //showing the actual virtual pin status 0/1
    OFF();
    Serial.print("off ok"); // this just helps me check where the code has  progressed
  }
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V3)
{
  int pinValue3 = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V3 to a variable

  if (pinValue3 == 1) {
    Serial.print("Police Lights: ON ");
    Serial.println(pinValue3);
    POL();
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Police Lights: OFF ");
    Serial.println(pinValue3);
    OFF();
    Serial.print("off ok"); // this just helps me check where the code has progressed
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Blynk.begin(Serial1, auth);
  Serial.println("Waiting for connections...");

  strip.begin();  //initializes the strip
  strip.show();  //turn off LEDs within NUMPIXELS
}

void OFF() {
  for (int i; i <= 72; i++) { //turn off strip
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
}

void DRL() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, white);
    strip.show();
    delay(4);
  }
}

void STI() {
  //turn on dinamic indicator
  for (int i = 0; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, amber);
    strip.show();
    delay(2);
  }

  //turn off dinamic indicator
  for (int i; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
  }
  delay (200);  //on condition delay
  strip.show();
  delay (500);  //off condition delay
}

void POL() {

  for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, red);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, red);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, red);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, red);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(100);

  for (int i = 37; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, blue);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 37; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 37; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, blue);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 37; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 37; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, blue);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 37; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 37; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, blue);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(30);

  for (int i = 37; i <= 72; i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, 0);
    strip.show();
  }
  delay(100);
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way the `BLYNK_WRITE` functions works is that they are called every time device gets an update of Virtual Pin value from the app. Now if you want to run something on a timer, or in a loop there is a function called `BlynkTimer`. You write your own function that you want to be looped and use this feature to define how often it should repeat. You can control execution by setting a boolean flag in the `BLYNK_WRITE` function and checking it in the loop, or by running the `enable()` and `disable()` methods of the timer. So, you can do something like this (without libraries, just an example):

```
BlynkTimer timer; // create timer

void myTimer() 
{
    // toggle an LED
    static bool state;
    digitalWrite(13, state);
    state = !state;
}

void setup()
{
  Blynk.begin(details); // blynk start
  timer.setInterval(1000L, myTimer); // repeat the timer once a second
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); // LED pin as output
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run(); // Runs all Blynk stuff
  timer.run(); // runs BlynkTimer
}
```

You can read more about it in the [docs](https://docs.blynk.io/en/blynk.edgent-firmware-api/blynk-timer).